# Where is Selenium picking up the Chrome version 85 reference?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an MSTest Project that is complaining about the Chrome Driver version.

> The Error Message:
> System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only >supports Chrome version 85 (SessionNotCreated)'

I have in my NuGet packages Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver - 97.0.4692.7100.
This version matches the installed Chrome browser version.

When I run or debug the test, the test runner seems to be calling a Chrome Driver that supports only Chrome version 85, but I cannot find any reference in the project to that driver.  Any idea where such a reference could be hiding?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Still unclear why/how this was happening, but I resolved it by killing the ChromeDriver executable in Task Manager, uninstalling the Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver, closing and reopeining Visual Studio and then reinstalling the Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver via NuGet.

All good now.